# Does Java Card support biometrics(in particular fingerprint authentication)?

Tags: java, sdk, fingerprint, javacard

The task is to implement a Java Card application (Applet) with biomentric (fingerprint)-based security. I see that since Java Card specification v2.2.2 the API contains a special package - `javacardx.biometry` - with interfaces such as `BioTemplate` and `BioBuilder` but I don't see any implementation.

1. Does this mean that for implementing a fingerprint authentication Applet that there is need to buy additional commercial SDK (e.g from Griaule Biometrics or [MegaMatcher](http://www.neurotechnology.com/megamatcher-on-card.html))? I would like to check if the features that are offered in standard Javacard API are sufficient (maybe I've just missed something);
2. If some 'third-party' sdk is needed could you recommend or share experience which one was used.

Comment: I rewrote your question a bit, Nazar. You may check the source to see some tricks to easily format the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javacardx.biometry` is only a generic interface which makes it easier for developers to implement an Applet for a card that **features biometry**. Otherwise you would have to use vendor specific code; now you can simply send a biometric template in a `byte[]` to the vendor specific implementation. If you would switch smart card implementations you would have little to no work to do to port you Applet.

Java Card seems to place no restrictions on the API. So yes, you need a combined package from a Java Card vendor and a biometrics supplier to be able to use match on card. The availability of many API's (and cipher constants) in Java Card does not mean that those features are present on these cards.